# How to upload videos via single page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I can't understand how can I get video id from WordPress media library and put in video player in single.php?Which function do I need to use?

Example of my player :

```
<div class="news-column">

    <div class="news-item video-btn">
        <a href="/html/news/news_video/news5/1.mp4"  >
            <img src="/news/news_video/news5/video_img/4.jpg" alt="Thanks" class="video-item__image">
            <div class="news-item__overlay"></div>
            <div class="newsk-item__play"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 30 38" xml:space="preserve"><path class="icon-color" d="M0 0l30 19L0 38V0z"/></svg></div>

            <div class="news-item__content">

                <h3 class="news_client">Video Author Name</h3>
                <div class="news_title">Video Name</div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="lightbox">
<div id="lb-close">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 27 28" width="27" height="28" enable-background="new 0 0 27 28" xml:space="preserve"><polygon points="27,2.5 23.9,0 13.5,12.8 3.1,0 0,2.5 9.4,14 0,25.5 3.1,28 13.5,15.2 23.9,28 27,25.5 17.6,14 "/></svg>
</div>
<div id="lb-content">
 <!--   <div id="lb-prev">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 21 57" width="21" height="57" enable-background="new 0 0 21 57" xml:space="preserve"><polygon points="16.7,57 0,28.5 16.7,0 21,2.5 5.8,28.5 21,54.5 "/></svg>
    </div>-->
    <video id="lb-video" controls controlsList="nodownload">
        <source id="lb-video-src" src="#" type="video/mp4">
        <p>Sorry, your browser doesn\'t support HTML5 video.</p>
    </video>
   <!-- <div id="lb-next">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 21 57" width="21" height="57" enable-background="new 0 0 21 57" xml:space="preserve"><polygon points="4.3,57 21,28.5 4.3,0 0,2.5 15.2,28.5 0,54.5 "/></svg>
    </div>-->
</div>
```

---

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

When you select the video in the Wordpress media library, its information is shown in the right column on that page. In that right column there is also a button "copy URL". Clicking that will copy the complete file path, including the https and domain. Just put (i.e. paste) that into the `src` attribute of your `video` tag in the php template.